# No-IP doesn't work in my raspberry yet

Tags: networking, server, ssh

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 with OSMC and a Nextcloud server that I usually used outside home using No-IP. I had to reinstall apache2 one month ago, and I can't acess anymore from outside to it. If I try my No-IP adress at home in my browser it enters to the rooter cofiguration web, and when I try to access via ssh I get (or http):
connect to host xxx.xxx.xxx port 22: Connection refused

I don't know what can be failing. I haven't changed any router configuration, and I have reinstall no-ip program into the Raspberry.
Please, could you help me to investigate and solve the problem?

Thanks in advance and cheers,
Iam.

Answer (score -1):

The No-IP DUC (Dynamic Update Client) install as a service and setup instructions are here:-

https://ivancarosati.com/no-ip-with-raspberry-pi/